# Map multiple keys with lowdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

In [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) for Node.js, if I have a DB JSON like

```
[
    {
        "foo": "bar1",
        "tar": "ball1",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1
            },
            {
                "b": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "foo": "bar2",
        "tar": "ball2",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1
            },
            {
                "b": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can get all foo's: `[bar1, bar2]` with the query `db.get('test').map('foo').value();`

However **I need to get several keys**, like if I could do something like `db.get('test').map(['foo', 'data.a']).value();` to get:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "bar1",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "foo": "bar2",
        "data": [
            {
                "a": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is JSON, why not just use `array.map()`? As such:

```
var data = db.get('test');

var dataSelection = data.map(e => {
  return { foo: e.foo, a: data[0].a };
});
```