# Accessing Nested Json Values with LowDB with map

Tags: json, nested, electron

I have this json

```
[{
    "title": "Young Space",
    "rooms": [{
        "color": "white",
        "owner": "Filippo Clark"
        }, {
        "color": "black",
        "owner": "Adams Baker"
        } ]
}, {
  "title": "Old Heart",
    "rooms": [{
        "color": "violet",
        "owner": "Mason Nalty"
    }, {
        "color": "blue",
        "owner": "Ochoa Patel"
    } ]  
}]
```

Checking this [Map multiple keys with lowdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818849/map-multiple-keys-with-lowdb)

I found a solution to find all titles:

```
db.get('test').map('title').value();
```

but how can I get all colors?

I understood I can't do nor

```
db.get('test').map('title').value().map('color');
```

neither

```
db.get('eventi').map(key => { return presentations[key].p_speaker.value();}));
```

EDIT: I tried using flat()

```
db.get('test').map('title').value().flat();
```

But even with this result I can't use again the map function

The only solution to get ['white','black','violet','blue'] is to iterate with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved doing this:

db.get('test').map('title').value().flat().map(key => { return key.color } ) );